# Transformation of random normal variable $x/y^2$

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable, jacobian

If $x \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma_y)$ and $y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y)$ what is the distribution of $x/y^2$ using Jacobian method?

Comment: You have to detail in the question why you cannot solve this question via the Jacobian method. And please add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Hi, I want to make a transformation such as $u=x/y^2$ and $v=y$. I can find joint probability, but I need to take an integral in respect to v to find marginal distribution of u. the problem is I don't know how to take that integral and I am wondering maybe my choice of auxiliary variable $v$ is wrong.